# What is the difference between hilum of the lung and root of the lung?

Tags: lungs

**In my book they describe root of the lung like this:**
In the region of vertebrae TV to TVII, the mediastinal pleura refects off the mediastinum as a tubular, sleeve-like covering for structures (i.e., airway, vessels, nerves, lym-phatics) that pass between the lung and mediastinum. This sleeve-like covering, and the structures it contains, forms the root of the lung.

**And hilum of the lung like this**: 
The root joins the medial surface of the lung at an area referred to as the hilum of the lung. Here, the mediastinal pleura is continuous with the visceral pleura.

I dont see the difference between Root and hilum.
Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Hilum is an area(has only 2 dimensions) where as root is a body( has 3 dimensions).

> The root of lung is a short broad pedicle connecting the medial surface of the lung with the mediastinum. It consists of structures entering and leaving the lung at hilum. The root of lung is surrounded by a tubular sheath derived from the mediastinal pleura.

and

> The hilum is the area on the mediastinal surface of the lung through which structures enter or leave the lung.

<sub>Source: [pg no 239](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Textbook_of_Anatomy_Upper_Limb_and_Thora.html?id=-K1EAwAAQBAJ)</sub>

Consider the following image( edited by myself):

If the cylinder is root of lung then lateral opening(blue) is hilum.

[image: Taken from https://image.slidesharecdn.com/r-a-6-170509024427/95/anatomy-of-the-respiratory-system-6-27-638.jpg?cb=1498248177]

The region bounded( within the limits of pleural membrane) by those two planes is root of lung and the area bounded by the lateral plane is hilum.

Comment: Any reason for downvote so I may improve?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think you could mention which structures does the root consist of.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the lung is region of the mediastinal surface of the lung that lies between T5 and T7, it consist of the mediastinal and visceral pleura reflecting over the structures entering or leaving the lungs at the hilum like a sleeve.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It isn't clear to me as a non-expert in anatomy that this adds anything to the existing answer and reads more like a comment on that answer. In addition, answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then [edit] your answer accordingly. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

Root of of lung is a pedicle which connects medial surface of the lung with the mediastinum and lies at the level of 5,6,7 thoracic vertebrae.
It consists of structures going in and out through a triangular depression called hilum.

Comment: Welcome Prince Kumar. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when for guidance as to our ways. This is a perfectly reasonable answer, but we'd like you to add references as a rule to support the info. Enjoy Biology.